# Javascript/typescript loop to process one command at a time from array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array of commands and a method that runs them.

The array:

```
commandsArray = ['command one', 'command two', 'command three'];
```

Then I have a method that runs the commands but can only do one at the time:

```
runcommand(command) {

    execute(command);

 }
```

How can I get it to pick one at the time from the array and execute them?

Like doing this but in a loop:

```
runcommand('command one');
runcommand('command two');
runcommand('command three');
```

so it does one waits and this the next etc...like a batch file does.

How can I do this?

Comment: have you tried for loop ?

Comment: What does execute return? Is it asynchronous and does it return a Promise?

Comment: There is no return ... I just need an old fashioned run one at a time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
commandsArray.forEach(command => runcommand(command));
```